# Как декодировать строку байтов в целое число?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть HEX данные "10FA0E00" в этих данных 4 байта.
как их можно перевести в int
и отформатировать в таком виде?

```
device_settings = [{0: [3, 'field1'],
                    3: [1, 'field2'],
                    4: [1, 'field3'],
                    5: [3, 'field4']},
                   {0: [1, 'field5'],
                    1: [1, 'field6'],
                    2: [1, 'field7'],
                    3: [3, 'field8'],
                    },
                   {0: [1, 'field9'],
                    5: [1, 'field10']
                    },
                   {}
                   ]

field1 = {'0': 'Low',
          '1': 'reserved',
          '2': 'reserved',
          '3': 'reserved',
          '4': 'Medium',
          '5': 'reserved',
          '6': 'reserved',
          '7': 'High',
          }
field4 = {'0': '00',
          '1': '10',
          '2': '20',
          '3': '30',
          '4': '40',
          '5': '50',
          '6': '60',
          '7': '70',
          }
field8 = {'0': 'Very Low',
          '1': 'reserved',
          '2': 'Low',
          '3': 'reserved',
          '4': 'Medium',
          '5': 'High',
          '6': 'reserved',
          '7': 'Very High',
          }
```

Comment: `int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex('10FA0E00'), 'big')`.

Comment: `int('10FA0E00', 16)` - результат совпадает с предыдущим.